# Таблица из Базы Данных проблема с input(checkbox) и button

Tags: php, html, form, button, table

В общем есть вывод таблицы на сайт.
[image: Таблица]

Проблема - Когда нажимаю DELETE ничего не происходит, а когда ставлю галочку на checkbox нужная строка удаляется, мне бы хотелось убрать полностью checkbox'ы и чтоб удаление выполнялось только по кнопке DELETE.

Помогите...

**CODE:**

```
 <form method="POST" action="del.php">
                       <div class="card-body">
                          <div class="card-block">
                             <table class="table table-responsive-md text-center">
                                <thead>
                                   <tr>
                                      <th>#</th>
                                      <th></th>
                                      <th>User</th>
                                      <th>Key</th>
                                      <th>Date</th>
                                      <th>HWID</th>
                                      <th>Status</th>
                                      <th>Edit</th>
                                   </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                   <? while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($db_ex)): ?>
                                   <tr>
                                      <td><?=$row['id']?></td>
                                      <td>
                                         <input type="checkbox" id=<?=$row['id']?> value=<?=$row['id']?> name="CheatBase[]"/>
                                         <label for=<?=$row['id']?> ></label>
                                         </td>
                                      <td><?=$row['User']?></td>
                                      <td><?=$row['Key']?></td>
                                      <td><?=$row['Date']?></td>
                                      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success round"><?=$row['HWID'] ? $row['HWID'] : "NULL"?></button></td>
                                      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success round"><?=$row['State'] ? "No" : "Yes"?></button></td>
                                      <td>
                                         <a class="danger p-0" data-original-title="" title="">
                                         <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-danger px-2 py-1 text-uppercase white font-small-4 box-shadow-1 border-0">DELETE</button>
                                         </a>
                                      </td>
                                   </tr>
                                   <? endwhile; ?> 
                                </tbody>
                             </table>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                    </form>
```

Comment: Где само удаление? Тут код формы практически и не нужен
Есть подозрения что у вас просто где-то лишнее условие if checkbox = checked ->delete

Comment: Вот удаление

`
<?php
include("_access/connect.php");
if ($_POST) 
{
    $select_id = $_POST['CheatBase'][0];
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM `CheatBase` WHERE id IN(".$select_id.")");
    header("Location: /main");
}
?>
`

Comment: Ну, вообще, по-хорошему надо:
1. удалять столбец с чекбоксом
2. добавить в форму `name="id"`
3. брать с поста запись с этим id `$_POST['id'];`

а так-то не удаляет у вас потому что в запрос подставляете переменную, которую берёте с чекбокса

Comment: Не могли бы вы скинуть кодом, если не сложно.
Я слишком глуп(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <form method="POST" action="del.php">
                       <div class="card-body">
                          <div class="card-block">
                             <table class="table table-responsive-md text-center">
                                <thead>
                                   <tr>
                                      <th>#</th>
                                      <th>User</th>
                                      <th>Key</th>
                                      <th>Date</th>
                                      <th>HWID</th>
                                      <th>Status</th>
                                      <th>Edit</th>
                                   </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                   <? while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($db_ex)): ?>
                                   <tr>
                                      <td><input  name="id" value="<?=$row['id']?>" type="hidden"/><?=$row['id']?></td>
                                      <td><?=$row['User']?></td>
                                      <td><?=$row['Key']?></td>
                                      <td><?=$row['Date']?></td>
                                      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success round"><?=$row['HWID'] ? $row['HWID'] : "NULL"?></button></td>
                                      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success round"><?=$row['State'] ? "No" : "Yes"?></button></td>
                                      <td>
                                         <a class="danger p-0" data-original-title="" title="">
                                         <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-danger px-2 py-1 text-uppercase white font-small-4 box-shadow-1 border-0">DELETE</button>
                                         </a>
                                      </td>
                                   </tr>
                                   <? endwhile; ?> 
                                </tbody>
                             </table>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                    </form>
```

И теперь удаление:

```
<?php 
include("_access/connect.php"); 
if ($_POST){ 
$select_id = $_POST['id']; 
mysql_query("DELETE FROM CheatBase WHERE id=".$select_id."); 
header("Location: /main"); 
} 
?>
```

Comment: При нажатие DELETE в любой строке - удаляется только последняя строка в списке

Comment: p.s Поместил бутоны в форм и всё заработало

Answer (score 0):

Могу ошибаться, но подобную проблему я когда-то решил:

```
name="submit-<?= $row['id'] ?>"
```